# Handling reminder events in Google calendar

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api

I am performing calendar sync between my google and my web application.

Consider that the event is available in both the applications.

Now I am updating any field in my web application and performing a sync.

The reminder attribute is not a required tag for post request,but I am unable to set update the event without sending the reminder tag.

Now help me to retain the existing value of the Google remainder in Google Calendar

if I set usedefault : true the calendar's default remainder time is set 
If I set the tag setRemainder to null or empty the reminder in removed.

My question is how to retain the existing reminder value

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of options here.  First before preforming an [Event.update](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/update) do an [Event.Get](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/get) this will return an [EventResource](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events#resource) which you can then edit and post back as your Event.Update.

This is a second option is to use [events.patch](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/patch) which will preform a partal update on your event.  You only need to send the fields you want to update it doesn't update anything you dont send.  More info [here](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/performance#patch)

Useless tip: A patch can also be done with the update using the fields parameter, but its a pain.